# Vector-Valued Stone-Weierstrass Theorem?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, approximation-theory

The standard statement of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem is:

> Let $X$ be compact Hausdorff topological space, and $\mathcal{A}$ a subalgebra of the continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which separates points. Then $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $C(X, \mathbb{R})$ in sup-norm.

Most materials that I can find on the extension of Stone-Weierstrass theorem discuss only the multivariate case, i.e., $X\in \mathbb{R}^d$. I wonder whether this theorem can be extended to vector-valued continuous functions. Specifically, let $\mathcal{A}$ be a subalgebra of continuous functions $X\to \mathbb{R}^n$, with the multiplication defined componentwisely, i.e., $\forall f, g\in \mathcal{A}$, $fg = (f_1g_1, \ldots, f_ng_n)$. Then shall we claim $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $C(X, \mathbb{R}^n)$ in sup-norm if $\mathcal{A}$ separates points?

Any direct answer or reference would greatly help me!

Edit: As Nik Weaver points out, the original conjecture is false since the functions of the form $x\mapsto (f(x), 0, \ldots, 0)$ create a counter-example. I wonder whether there are non-trivial Weierstrass-type theorems on vector-valued functions. For instance, what if we further assume $\mathcal{A}$ is dense on each `axis'?

Comment: What is the multiplication in an "algebra of vector valued functions"? Or maybe you mean a structure of $C(X,\mathbb{R})$-module?

Comment: The statement is trivially false: the functions of the form $x \mapsto (f(x),0,\ldots, 0)$ with $f \in C(X)$ are sup-norm closed and separate points.

Comment: @NikWeaver Thanks for the counterexample here! I've added a short comment in the post.

Comment: @PietroMajer The componentwise multiplication induces an "algebra of vector valued functions", doesn't it?

Comment: I see, thanks!  Then it is like the algebra $C(X\times\{1,\dots,n\},\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Maybe it would be instructive to do the special case where $X$ is a single point.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Thanks for the suggestion! I'm more interested in the case where $X$ is a compact interval like $[0, 1]$, which might be fundamentally different from the case where $X$ is a single point.

Comment: @PietroMajer I'm not sure whether I'm correct. I guess it is like the algebra $C(X, \mathbb{R}\times \{1, \ldots, n\})$?

Comment: I believe it is isomorphic to $C(X \times \{1, \dots, n\}, \mathbb R)$ at least as a topological algebra. Applying Stone--Weierstrass to that algebra it seems the correct condition is that for $x, y \in X$ and any pair of indices $i, j$ there exists $f \in \mathcal A$ with $f_i(x) \ne f_j(y)$.

Comment: no, just write $f(x,j)$ instead of $f_j(x)$. It's an algebra isomorphism wrto the one you said. So in fact it is a way to include your setting in the usual one.

Comment: @lambda yes, that what i was saying

Comment: @lambda This is inspiring! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @PietroMajer I really appreciate the detailed discussions here! Thanks again!

Answer (score 12):

I think that you want something like this:

Let $E\to X$ be a (finite rank) vector bundle over a compact, Hausdorff topological space $X$, let $\mathcal{A}\subset C(X,\mathbb{R})$ be a subalgebra that  separates points, and let $\mathcal{E}\subset C(X,E)$ be an $\mathcal{A}$-submodule of the $C(X,\mathbb{R})$-module of continuous section of $E\to X$.  Suppose that, at every point $x\in X$, the set $\{\,e(x)\ |\ e\in\mathcal{E}\ \}$ spans $E_x$.  Then $\mathcal{E}$ is dense in $C(X,E)$ with respect to the sup-norm defined by any norm on $E$.

**Addendum:** Here is a sketch of the argument:  First, by an easy compactness argument, one can show that $\mathcal{E}$ contains a finite set $e_1,\ldots e_m$ such that $e_1(x),e_2(x),\ldots,e_m(x)$ spans $E_x$ for all $x\in X$.  Then $\mathcal{E}$ contains all the sections of the form $$a_1\, e_1 + \cdots + a_m\,e_m$$ where $a_i\in\mathcal{A}$, and every section $e\in C(X,E)$ can be written in the form $$e = f_1\, e_1 + \cdots + f_m\,e_m$$  for some functions $f_i\in C(X,\mathbb{R})$. By the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem, for any given $\delta>0$, we can choose $a_i\in \mathcal{A}$ so that $\|f_i-a_i\|<\delta$  for all $1\le i\le m$.  Now the equivalence of all norms in finite dimensional vector spaces can be applied (together with the compactness of $X$) to conclude that $\mathcal{E}$ is dense in $C(X,E)$ in any sup-norm derived from a norm on the (finite rank) vector bundle $E$.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum! While I'm digesting this, I have a quick question here. Does this result hold for matrix-valued subalgebras, i.e., $\mathcal{A} \subset C(X, \mathbb{R}^{n\times n})$ equipped with matrix multiplication?

Comment: @mw19930312:  I'm confused by your question.  Could you state what you mean by 'this result' more precisely?

Comment: @mw19930312:  I'm sorry, but I don't know what you mean by assuming that $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$.  In my answer, $E\to X$ is a vector bundle over $X$ and $\mathcal{A}$ is a subset of $C(X,\mathbb{R})$.  Maybe you mean something like "If $\mathcal{A}\subset C(X,\mathrm{End}(E))$ is an algebra of bundle maps from $E$ to $E$ and $\mathcal{E}\subset C(X,E)$ is a space of sections that is an $\mathcal{A}$-module, then under what conditions can we conclude that $\mathcal{E}$ is dense in $C(X,E)$ in the sup-norm induced by any norm on $E$"?

Comment: Hi Robert, sorry for coming back to this question after it is posted for a month. I believe you are interpreting this correctly, I'm looking for the case of $\mathcal{A}\subset C(X, \mathrm{End}(E))$. If the same result holds, would you mind referring me a detailed proof of this?

Comment: @mw19930312:  That's OK.  What I don't know is what you want to assume about $\mathcal{A}\subset C(X,\mathrm{End}(E))$.  Is it a subalgebra?  Are you asking for checkable conditions that would guarantee that $\mathcal{A}$ is $C^0$-dense in $C(X,\mathrm{End}(E))$?

Comment: I assume $\mathcal{A}$ is a subalgebra. We can assume $\mathcal{A}$ separate points first. Then I wonder whether your answer still holds, i.e., $\mathcal{E}$ is dense in $C(X, E)$, where $\mathcal{E}$ is an $\mathcal{A}$-module, if span of $\{e(x) |e\in \mathcal{E}\}$ equals to $E_x$. If it holds, would you mind referring me a proof?

Comment: Also, if $\mathcal{A}$ does not separate points, then can we identify the denseness of $\mathcal{E}$ through checking whether $\mathcal{E}\big\vert_{[x]}$ spans $E\big\vert_{[x]}$, where $[x]$ is the equivalent class of $x$ under $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: @mw19930312:  I'm confused by your bringing in $\mathcal{E}$ in a question about $\mathcal{A}$.  The question about $\mathcal{A}$ being dense in $C(X,\mathrm{End}(E))$ makes sense without any reference to an $\mathcal{A}$-module $\mathcal{E}\subset \Gamma(X,E)$.  Let's not lose sight of your objective:  Is it $\mathcal{A}$ or $\mathcal{E}$.  Also, I'm not sure what 'separates points' means in reference to $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: @RobertBryant: I would like to use this in a work of mine, but in order to save space, it would be preferable to give a reference instead of a proof. Do you know of any, please?

Comment: @AlexM.:  I'm sorry, but I don't know a reference where the above statement is proved explicitly.  It's certainly a well-known result, though.  For example, the statement that every continuous section of a smooth vector bundle over a compact manifold can be uniformly approximated by a smooth section, which is used all over the place in differential topology, is a special case, but I'm not sure that I've ever seen anyone give a reference.  It's kind of a folk theorem.  Maybe it's an exercise in a introductory topology course.  Maybe, Spanier?

Answer (score 7):

This is a comment, not an answer but I am, alas, not entitled.  Vector valued Stone-Weierstraß theorems were studied in great detail in the second half of the last century and there is a comprehensive monograph on the subject by João Prolla ("Weierstraß-Stone, the theorem", 1993).  Not on topic, but he also considered the case of bounded, continuous vector-valued functions on non-compact spaces, using the strict topology of R.C. Buck.

Comment: Great thanks for the references here! By any chance, could you refer me to some other materials on this topic? The book by João Prollaa appears very difficult for me to find. I've got a note by him named `Approximation of Vector-Valued Functions' in 1977. Is there any recent update on this notes?

Comment: The book title written by Yoda has been.